# Determine a basis of the subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine a basis for this subspace: W={(M∈M³×³(ℝ):M^t=M}

I don't even know where to start. Does this involve using upper and lower triangular matrices?

Comment: If you were to write an arbitrary $3\times 3$ symmetric matrix using as few letters and variables as possible... how many letters do you need?  For example, if I were to write an arbitrary $2\times 2$ matrix which wasn't necessarily symmetric I might write $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$... but if it were a symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix instead, I could say something about $b$ and $c$ there...

Comment: Then, recognize that $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ could be written as $a\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+b\cdot\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+\dots$

Comment: The dimension of the space of 3x3 symmetric matrices is 6, so [1 0 0, 0 0 0, 0 0 0], [0 0 0, 0 1 0, 0 0 0], [0 0 0, 0 1 0, 0 0 0], [0 0 0, 0 0 0, 0 0 1], [0 1 0, 1 0 0, 0 0 0], [0 0 1, 0 0 0, 1 0 0], [0 0 0, 0 0 1, 0 1 0]. (The commas separate the rows in the matrix)

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to typeset with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ on this site.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly found in the comments, an arbitrary $3\times 3$ symmetric matrix could be written as $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\b&d&e\\c&e&f\end{bmatrix}$ and this could be rewritten and split up as $a\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}+\dots$

giving one option for the basis of this space being

$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$